# Power BI PQ Oracle.Database the query is too long to be diplayed

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi, powerquery

I am using function Oracle.Database and my SQL query is of length bigger than 10 000 rows. That is why I get message:the query is too long to be diplayed,
And Run button is inactive.

Is it possible to enlarge the allowed length of SQL query in Oracle.Database settings or anywhere in Power BI?

Comment: I am delighted. length is definitely remarkable

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't use it. However, perhaps you could create a **view** (in database) and then base your Power BI query on that view; could/should shorten query length *a lot*.

Comment: A query's length would be measured in *characters*, not rows -- the number of *rows* the query returns should pose no restrictions on its use. Although in theory you can bypass the UI by using the advanced editor and pasting your query there, if it's truly as long as you say it is, the PowerQuery M parser would have trouble processing it too. A view is one option, per Littlefoot; the other would be to take a critical look at your query as to *why* it's so long. This typically indicates a more fundamental problem with your database design or the way the query's written.